# Of the first 100 terms in fibonacci sequence, how many are odd?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, as I tried to solve this questions I used the following : 
$\newcommand{\aa}{\mathbf{a}}$
$\aa_1 =1,~~ 
\aa_2 = 1$
and we know that in Fibonacci sequence, $\aa_n = \aa_{n-1} +\aa_{n-2}. $
Hence, 
$\aa_3 = 2,~~
\aa_4 = 3,~~ 
\aa_5 = 5,~~
\aa_6 = 8$

We notice an *Odd Odd Even* pattern starting from $\aa_1$. Since we are assuming $100$ terms, we take $100/3$, which approximates to $33.333$ (do we round this off to 33?) 
Proceeding this way we know that there is one even in each of these $33$ terms. Thus, number of even terms = $33$.

So, odd terms $= 100 - 33 = 67$.

Is this the correct approach to this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 5):

Odd, Odd, Even, Odd, Odd, Even, is a correct observation.

This is a valid approach.

Comment: Do you want to add a sentence of why rounding is not ideal and how to consider the last term?

Comment: I am not sure, how do we even consider the last term? Reason I rounded was because I knew number of terms cannot be in decimals.

Comment: @IshaanSingh Next time, when you have a more complex pattern, say Odd, Even, Odd, Odd, Even, Even lets say (length 6). first find the total number of repetitions in the first hundred terms (16x6) and then add on the next four (odd, even, odd, odd)

Comment: so in your case, just take the first 33 (odd, odd, even) and then add the next odd (#100) for a total of 67 odd terms, or 33 even terms

Answer (score 1):

You know that there are 33 full 3-cycles inside this 100 element segment. the 100th element starts a new cycle, and the cycle start is *Odd*, so that indeed you get 67 times *Odd*.

However, had you used the other convention $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, etc. then the cycle would have been *Even, Odd, Odd* and the 100th element $F_{99}$ would be *Even*, giving $34$ times *Even* and $66$ times *Odd*. So simple rounding will not in all cases give the correct result.